# Received string over socket does not compare in python

Tags: java, string, sockets, python-3.x, compare

I am trying to compare a string i received over a socket in python send from Java.
It fails to compare. If i run a simple If statement in IDLE, it works. But when i try to receive a string and compare it.

Java code for sending the string:

```
String nummer = "1";
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
out.println(nummer);
```

Python code:

```
while True:
# establish a connection
clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()

print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
returnmsg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
command = str(returnmsg.decode('utf-8'))
print(command)
if command == 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print('open')
    time.sleep(1)
if command == '0':
    time.sleep(1)
    print('close')
    time.sleep(1)
if command != '1' and command != '0':
    print('something else')
clientsocket.close()
print('Socket closed')
```

The output shown on the python console is as follows:

```
Got a connection from ('192.168.0.101', 50148)
1

something else
Socket closed
```

It always ends up in the last statement. I tried comparing like:

```
if command == '1':
if command == "1":
```

What it should do, in java (android) i have 3 buttons. 2 buttons just send a 1 or 0 (in string). The other sends a string with more characters. The string itself is not important.

It always ends up in the last statement. Which it should not do. And it does not even enter the right statement. As it should print "open" when i click the button in my android app.

Any one knows how to solve this so it enters the right statement and does not enter the last?

Cheers.

Comment: have you tried to use Netty Project??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably got a line feed on the wire so you ought to compare against `"1\n"` or `.strip()` it

Comment: It was that simple. Solved my problem. Didnt look for it as it didnt actually print the "\n". Thanks!

Comment: The same apply to JAVA. Use receivedString.trim() in JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I used the code below and found I had `\x00` on the end of my string which did not show when printing/converting or any other method.

```
tmp = returnmsg.split()
print tmp
```